# Bootstrap row with height which depends on first col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make wrapper for youtube video, that contains 2 cols:

- Video block
- Scrollable list block like playlist

[image]

So, height of list block depends on height of video (which is responsive). How can I perform this?
Thanks.

Comment: Flexbox...simple answer.

Comment: Any example for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't think of an easy way to resize the list. Whenever a video is loaded you need to get the height of video using javascript and set the `max-height` value for the list.

Assuming your list id is "vidList", you can modify the `max-height` like the following inside javascript:

```
document.getElementById("vidList").style.maxHeight = vidHeight;
```

Following is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/learningloop/pen/VvLxdb?editors=110) i tried using fixed size `iframe` and `ul`. Following is the [preview](http://codepen.io/learningloop/full/VvLxdb/).